# MySQL not accepting remote connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtualbox, chef-infra, vagrant

Background: I'm using 2 nodes, one I'm calling `services` and one I'm calling `storage`. I'm using chef to provision the nodes and I'm using vagrant to virtualise the nodes. ***All passwords are virtualised local environments only, before people get upset***

I've had it setup before where the storage node has been running MySQL and the services node has been running php and able to connect to the storage node.

Recently I've completely destroyed and `up`ed the VMs again and the storage node is no longer accepting connections to MySQL from remote hosts

```
vagrant@services:~$ mysql -u web_app -ppassword -h 192.168.33.2
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.33.2' (111)

vagrant@storage:~$ mysql -u root -ppassword
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 46
Server version: 5.5.36-34.0-632.precise (Ubuntu)
```

I've setup my MySQL permissions as such http://pastie.org/pastes/8946859/text?key=xdtlskj5gwl5qypowcvpa

Following the advice given on a few other questions dotted around on the site

```
vagrant@storage:~$ less /etc/my.cnf | grep bind-address
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

vagrant@storage:~$ sudo netstat -lpn | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6008/mysqld
```

This to me looks like MySQL is listening on address 0.0.0.0 on port 3306, which should  be ok.

Really lost by this one, especially as I'm using chef and don't recall changing any config options since it last worked...

Comment: I have no bind-address at all mentioned, than it listens to anything as well. 
Does you mysqld log mention anything?

Comment: `less file | grep pattern` - you know you can just `grep pattern file`, right?  :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved my own problem to an extent. Just checked /etc/**mysql**/my.cnf and it looks like the bind address was set to 127.0.0.1

Have changed this to 0.0.0.0 restarted and the server and can now connect remotely

Just got to make this work with chef again...